# CodeIgniter pagination link URL generation behavior

Tags: pagination, hyperlink, codeigniter-2

At first I thought I did something wrong and that links are being generated incorrectly, but it was weird to me that the content was displaying as it was supposed to, so I did some search and found that CI's pagination link URLs actually contain offset instead of the page number. Now, while that is convenient for fetching things from the database, I find it very unintiutive while looking at the URL itself. For example, if I have 9 objects that I want to display, 3 objects per page, I will have 3 pages, and the links for page 2 and 3 will be url/3 and url/6, respectively.

Is there a way to have pagination generate URLs with actual pages instead of the Offset? I can calculate the offset easily with page and per_page info.

Comment: did you use this $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

Comment: Oh wow...I read through the entire doc page and somehow managed to overlook that option. Probably because it was 5am when I was checking it. Thanks a lot, that must be it. Going to test it now

Comment: Tested and it works, thanks a lot! If you can post it as an answer so I can accept it that would be cool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the pagination. There is an option available

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

If you set it to true it will generate the page numbers.

You can read the documentation here

User Guide